# how to ensure python 2.7 script run every 1 second and can still resume despite any exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, resume

This is my Python 2.7 script

First I have this class in a file called `safe-scheduler.py`

```
import logging

from traceback import format_exc
import datetime

from schedule import Scheduler

logger = logging.getLogger('schedule')
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())

class SafeScheduler(Scheduler):

    def __init__(self, reschedule_on_failure=True):
        self.reschedule_on_failure = reschedule_on_failure
        Scheduler.__init__(self)

    def _run_job(self, job):
        try:
            Scheduler._run_job(self, job)
        except Exception:
            tb = format_exc()
            logger.error(tb)
            job.last_run = datetime.datetime.now()
            job._schedule_next_run()
```

Then I write this in another file called `read-mercury.py`

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pycurl, urllib, json
from datetime import datetime
from safe_scheduler import SafeScheduler

# .... a lot of code later

import time

def job():
    print(reader.read())
    print(reader.get_model())
    time_now = "{:%B %d, %Y at %H:%M:%S}".format(datetime.now())
    print( time_now)

scheduler = SafeScheduler()
scheduler.every(1).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    scheduler.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

So this will correctly attempt to run every 1 second and then when it encounters error, it will not resume.

How do I make this code resume, despite the failure?

**UPDATE:**

I change the code to this

```
        except Exception:
            tb = format_exc()
            print(tb)
            #logger.error(tb)
            job.last_run = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Then I purposely let it run for a few iterations and then I purposely cut off the internet and then reconnect.

I notice I get caught in an endless loop of showing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   FIle .... line 19, in _run_job
      Scheduler._run_job(self, job)
  File .... line 129 in _run_job
      ret = job.run()
   File ..... line 377 , in run
      ret = self.job_func()
    File ..... read-mercury.py line 43 in job 
      print(reader.read())
 RuntimeError: LLRP Reader Send Messages failed
```

I know that the Runtime Error is due to the network being cut off. But even when the connection is restored, the error message is still being called endlessly.

What should I do?

Comment: What is this failure you are dealing with, exactly? Can you provide the Traceback?

Comment: the script basically will poll something. and sometimes the network dies. I previously had this line `logger = logging.getLogger('schedule')` but then I get a `No handlers can be found for logger “schedule"` So I added the nullhandler.

Comment: okay i have commented out this line `logger.error(tb)` and purposely cut off my network halfway thru the script. the script will resume even after the network is cut off, so I guess, my remaining issue is there a way to use the logger properly? EDIT: I spoke too soon. I tried again the second time cutting off, the script did not resume. Please advise.

Comment: Have you narrowed down where exactly this is raising? Is it raising with the exact same exception each time? Have you narrowed down if it is happening outside where you are currently wrapping your exception? Also, you should determine what exceptions you are catching instead of using a catch all.

Comment: How do I narrow? I am pretty new to python by the way.

Comment: You narrow it down by trying to create a [mcve] that just contains the code required to cause the problem.

Comment: Also, in terms of narrowing down the problem. The process would be the same for any language. Using your IDE, you could use a debugger to determine where it fails. You can set more logging to see at what point of your code it is actually failing. Furthermore, you should take note of the *exact* Traceback you are getting. The exception will give you an indication of what is going on. This will help you put together, as mentioned by someone else, a proper [mcve] to help further diagnose this.

Comment: I have managed to get the traceback by simply using print instead of the logger. Question updated above.

Comment: I have tried several things including attempting to restart the script `read-mercury`. No avail